# how to solve python pandas import error while building docker

Tags: python, pandas, docker, docker-compose

Hi all I have to build a docker for my python code and while running the docker I am getting import pandas import error as below

```
File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
import pandas as pd
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 7, in 
<module>
  from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
File "pandas/src/numpy.pxd", line 865, in init pandas.hashtable 
 (pandas/hashtable.c:38266)
ValueError: numpy.ufunc has the wrong size, try recompiling
rahuls-MacBook-Pro-2:date inndata$ docker build -t inndata/dates
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
 See 'docker build --help'.
```

Please help me diagnose the error.

my requirements file:-

```
numpy >= 1.1, < 2.0
pandas >= 0.13, < 0.22
nose >= 1.3.1, < 1.4
nolearn == 0.5b1
Flask == 1.0.2
pymongo ==  3.7.1
msgpack==0.5.6
spacy == 2.0.12
```

my docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:18.10
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-dev python3-pip build-essential
RUN pip3 install uwsgi
RUN apt-get install vim -y
 COPY ./ ./app
WORKDIR ./app
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

in app.py I have my python code.

Comment: You might have two versions of numpy. Remove one of them.

Comment: I have tried it but no use still I am getting same error @Mohit Motwani

Comment: Maybe try `pip` instead of `pip3`. Similar github issue: [#16715](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16715)